# Why isn't the definite article used in front of "a comma"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

The word *comma* only means the mark ",", but why does everyone say it as *a comma* or *commas* not *the comma*; likewise *a question mark* not *the question mark* only indicating the mark "?".

Comment: **a** refers to any instance of the thing.

Comment: Your entire question is based on a false premise. The phrase _the comma_ is used [often enough](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+comma+is+used%22&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=bks&biw=1536&bih=832). But it makes sense that instances of _a comma_ or _commas_ would be more common.

Comment: So, "put a definite article in the sentence" can be used?

Comment: _Put a definite article in the sentence_ absolutely could be used.

Comment: What's the difference of put a / the definite article in the sentence?

Comment: There is negligible difference in meaning. Either one means that the writer needs to include the word "the" somewhere in the sentence. We can say, "Put a definite article in" because we are talking about one instance of the definite article. We can also say, "Put the definite article in" because we are talking about a specific word (i.e., the word "the"). The two sentences may get interpreted a little bit differently, but the underlying meaning is essentially the same for both.

Comment: Wow that needs lots of thinking

Comment: Which one is more nature between A indicating a instance and The indicating a defintion?

Comment: Sorry, this discussion is straying too far from your original question, so this will be my last comment here. That said, this is not a question about, "Which is more natural?" or even, "Which is more common?" – the answers to those questions are irrelevant. You must be able to tell when one should be used, the other should be used, or either one can be used, That is entirely dependent on **context**, not some three- or four-word snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JR pointed out, the confusion seems to be coming from the very first statement you make:

> The word ***comma*** only means the mark ","

I believe you are saying ***the comma*** is always used to refer to a specific instance of a comma. This may be true, but it doesn't preclude ***a comma*** from referring to any instance of a comma.

I think a more accurate and complete statement is this:

> The word ***comma*** can mean any mark ","

This allows ***a comma*** and ***the comma*** to have separate usages and still live in peaceful harmony in the same universe.